# Do scrolls benefit from magic perks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, do magic scrolls benefit from perks such as Rune Master or Quiet Casting?

UESP has no information on the topic and googling has proven fruitless so far.

Comment: I've played through the game about 10 times... and I have never used a single scroll... ever.

Comment: I‘m trying to build a no-magicka trapper build, so I‘d like to work with scrolls for rune spells. Sort of like a DND rogues „Use Magic Device“ skill

Comment: I'm planning to investigate this myself when I get chance to boot up my PC version, but [this Wikia page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Scrolls_(Skyrim)) says that the effects of some scrolls do benefit from some perks, it just doesn't detail which.

Comment: Like @Nelson, I seldom use scrolls.  In fact in most of my play-throughs I'll have used exactly 3 scrolls ... and those where at J'zargo's request.

Comment: @KallumTanton nice, I‘m looking forward to your results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the Quiet Casting perk does work on scrolls I play as a mage in skyrim and I would have been put in jail for life by now if the scrolls made noise when you cast them

Comment: In addition to your perks, various potions will also affect spell casting from a scroll.  For example, casting Mayhem from a scroll after consuming a Fortify Illusion Potion will be more effective.